# Split Array By Values In Sequence

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

Is there an easy (linq?) way to split an `int` array into new arrays based off unbroken numerical sequences? For example given this pseudo code:

```
[Fact]
public void ArraySpike()
{
   var source = new[] {1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9, 12, 13, 24};

   var results = SplitArray(source);

    Assert.True(results[0] == new[] {1, 2, 3});
    Assert.True(results[1] == new[] {7, 8, 9}); 
    Assert.True(results[2] == new[] {12, 13}); 
    Assert.True(results[3] == new[] {24}); 
}

public int[][] SplitArray(int[] source)
{
    return source.???   
}
```

Comment: What constitutes a group? Every 5 digits? (1-5, 6-10, 11-15, etc) ?

Comment: @igor no, numbers in unbroken sequence, so group1 = 1,2,3 group2 = 7,8,9 group3 = 12,13 group4 = 24

Comment: Ah, that was just a coincidence then.

Comment: Not sure why the downvotes (*maybe no attempt?*), I think the question is rather interesting.

Comment: Possibly, I have an "ugly" attempt, but then that would be for code review I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can work with the linq extension `Aggregate`. My seeding is not very elegant *but* that is easy enough to change. The `results` variable will contain the array of arrays and they are actually of type `List<T>` because that way they can be easily grown in the function where an array [] is always of fixed size.

*This also assumes the source is already ordered and unique, if that is not the case add `.OrderBy(x => x).Distinct()`*

```
var source = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9, 12, 13, 24 };
var results = new List<List<int>>{new List<int>()};

var temp = source.Aggregate(results[0], (b, c) =>
{
    if (b.Count > 0 && b.Last() != c - 1)
    {
        b = new List<int>();
        results.Add(b);
    }
    b.Add(c);
    return b;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I dug up this extension method from my personal collection:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> GroupConnected<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list, Func<T,T,bool> connectionCondition)
{
    if (list == null)
    {
        yield break;
    }
    using (var enumerator = list.GetEnumerator())
    {
        T prev = default(T);
        var temp = new List<T>();
        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            T curr = enumerator.Current;
            {
                if(!prev.Equals(default(T)) && !connectionCondition(prev, curr))
                {
                    yield return temp;
                    temp = new List<T>();
                }
                temp.Add(curr);
            }
            prev = curr;
        }
        yield return temp;
    }
}
```

It solves the problem in a more general sense: split up a sequence in subsequences of elements that are "connected" somehow. It traverses the sequence and collects each element in a temporary list until the next item isn't "connected". It then returns the temporary list and begins a new one.

Your array elements are connected when they have a difference of `1`:

```
var results = source.GroupConnected((a,b) => b - a == 1);
```