# How to get repeated values in LINQ

Tags: linq

```
var numbs4 = new List<dynamic>() { 12, 9, 75,75, 23, 12, 33, 34, 54, 21, 22 };
```

Hi how do I get `{75,75}` from an ascending order using LINQ?

Using `Take()` you limit the number of rows

```
var result = numbs4.OrderByDescending(x=>x).Skip(1).Take(1).ToList();
```

Result : 75

I want the identical to be involved as well: `{75,75}`
Take restrict you, what I am going to do?

Comment: You can use [this extension method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46595110/861716), but with condition `a == b`).

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to get all items matching the first-after-max, you could group by, order groups by the key in descending order, and pick the entire initial group, like this:

```
var result = numbs4
    .GroupBy(x =>x)
    .OrderByDescending(g => g.Key)
    .Skip(1)
    .First()            // That's the second group now
    .ToList();
```

[Demo.](https://ideone.com/LH8JQU)

Comment: how about 75,75,73,73,73,72,72  , then i need 73,73,73

Comment: @EmblezEd Add `Skip(1) after `OrderBy()` before `First()`.

Comment: yeah thanks ,please tell me that i am not allowed in stackoverflow to copy your  answer and paste it as my answer without modifying it first as my answer?

Comment: @EmblezEd When an answer needs only a small modification, Stack Overflow expects you to suggest an edit or to comment for the author to make an edit. You post a new answer when you find an answer independently.